# Electric potential due to 1d dipole at the interface

Tags: electrostatics

I would like to calculate the interface potential due to a dipole present at the lateral heterojunction of two materials.
For a 2d interface, it is given by $\frac{eD}{\epsilon_0}$, where D is the dipole density.
For the 1d case, How do I go about this?